# Regexp_extract everything after appearance of '-q_'

Tags: sql, regex

Have strings containing 'q_' which I want to extract everything that comes after it. Some rows contain occurrence of q_ which I want everything that occurs after it. Example values in the column are:

```
prod-q_cat_trait_cat_social_issue
_prod-q_body_modification_graffiti
event_tickets
dappled_grey
_prod-q_cat_tech_support
```

What is wrong with my regular expression as I'm trying to remove the trailing '_' after q.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(queue_id, '[^q_]+$')
```

Is just returning

```
issue
```

I've also tried the split method:

```
SPLIT(queue_id, 'q_')[OFFSET(2)]
```

But this returns

```
Array index 2 is out of bounds (overflow)
```

Any suggestions. Thanks! (I am using Google Cloud SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a *capturing group*, you may **extract all after the first** `q_` with:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(queue_id, 'q_(.*)')
```

You may **extract all after the last** `q_` with:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(queue_id, '.*q_(.*)')
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/IIBAgX/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/IIBAgX/3).

Here, `q_` finds the first occurrence of `q_` and `(.*)` grabs the rest of the line into Group 1, and this is the value returned by `REGEXP_EXTRACT`. `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible, that is why the second regex will start capturing the rest of the line after the last occurrence of `q_`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this : `q_([^q_]+)$`? You'll have what you want in the first group.

Edit: this one match all the cases > `(?(?<=-q_).*|^((?!-q_).)*$)`

Comment: That works, but returns null for the rows that don't have 'q_' in the value

Comment: Can you send the examples you use?

Comment: If you have `q_` so you want to extract only what come next else you want all the string? If so you can use => `(?:q_)?([^q_]+)$`

Comment: No that's not working. I have included examples above. If a row value I don't need to extract contains a 'q' is it getting split e.g. requirements is becoming 'uirements'.

Comment: Ok, find it > `(?(?<=-q_).*|^((?!-q_).)*$)`

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL uses MySQL.  I think the simplest method is `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(queue_id, '-q_', -1)
```